# I get the error : - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment-processing

My Payment.js :-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./Payment.css"
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider'
import CheckoutProduct from './CheckoutProduct';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CardElement,useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';
import { getBasketTotal } from './reducer';
import axios from "./axios";
import {db} from "./firebase";

function Payment() {
    const [{basket, user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const history = useHistory();

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const [succeeded, setSucceeded]=useState(false);
    const [processing,setProcessing] = useState(""); 
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] =useState(true);
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] =useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() =>{
        //generate the special stripe secret which allows us to charge the customer

        const getClientSecret = async () => {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'Post',
                // Stripe expects the total in a currencies submits
                url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
            });
            setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
        }
        
        getClientSecret();
    },[basket])

console.log("THE SCRET KEY IS >>>>>", clientSecret)
console.log("Hey! I am the user: My props", user);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) =>{
        // do all the fancy stripe stuff 
        event.preventDefault();
        setProcessing(true);
        
        const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
            }
        }).then(({paymentIntent})=>{
            
            db.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection('orders').doc(paymentIntent.id).set({basket: basket,amount: paymentIntent.amount,created: paymentIntent.created})

            setSucceeded(true);
            setError(null);
            setProcessing(false)

            dispatch({
                type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
            })
            history.replace('/orders')
        })
    }

    const handleChange = event =>{
        //handle for changes in tht CardElement
        // and display any error as the customer types their card details
        setDisabled(event.empty);
        setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "")
    }

    return (
        <div className="payment">
            <div className="payment__container">
            <h1>
                Checkout Products(
                {<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items
                </Link>})
            </h1>

             {/* payment section-delivery address  */}
                <div className="payment__section">
                    <div className="payment__title">
                            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="payment__address" >
                        <p>{user?.email}</p> 
                        <p>123 React Lane</p> 
                        <p>Los Angeles, CA</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>  
              {/* payment section-delivery address   */}
              <div className="payment__section">
                    <div className="payment__title">
                        <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="payment__items">
                        {basket.map( item =>
                            <CheckoutProduct
                                id={item.id}
                                title={item.title}
                                image={item.image}
                                price={item.price}
                                rating={item.rating}  />
                                 )}
                    </div>
                </div>
              {/* payment section-delivery address   */}
              <div className="payment__section paymentBox">
                  <div className="payment__title">
                      <h3>Payment Method</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div className="payment__details">
                      {/* stripe magic will goes here */}
                  
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                                <CardElement  onChange={handleChange}/>

                                <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                                    <CurrencyFormat
                                     renderText={(value)=>(
                                     <h3>Order total {value}</h3>
                                     )}
                                     decimalScale={2}
                                     value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                                     displayType={"text"}
                                     thousandSeparator={true}
                                     prefix={"₹"}
                                    />
                                    <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                                        <span>{processing?<p>processing</p>:"Buy Now"}</span>
                                    </button>                                                     
                               </div>

                               {/* Error */}
                               {error && <div>{error}</div>}
                            </form>
                  </div>  
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Payment;
```

And the error is here :-

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) =>{
    // do all the fancy stripe stuff 
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);
const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
    }
}).then(({paymentIntent})=>{

    db.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection('orders').doc(paymentIntent.id).set({basket: basket,amount: paymentIntent.amount,created: paymentIntent.created})

    setSucceeded(true);
    setError(null);
    setProcessing(false)

    dispatch({
        type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
    })
    history.replace('/orders')
})
```

}

Now, I can understand that it means to say that **paymentIntent** is undefined but why is it undefined?
I tried doing console.log(paymentIntent) inside this function and it said that paymentIntent is undefined.

I have checked for all spelling errors and firebase config.js too.

My application doesn't make the collections in The Firebase neither does it replace the page from /payment to /orders.

I made this app again from scratch and yet the same error occurs.
I tried to change my **Firebase** and **Stripe** accounts yet I get this error.

Please tell how to fix this error.
If you need any other file, I will send you.

Comment: Should `paymentIntent` be destructured from the argument passed to the `.then` of the promise chain? What if you just `.then(arg => {...)` and log or set a breakpoint to examine `arg`?

Comment: Instead of destructuring directly, Could you also check the `errors` object that comes in the result. I think its returning some errors and that is why you do not have any paymentIntent present.

Comment: How do I check the errors object in the result?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Payment.js:54
    at async handleSubmit (Payment.js:45)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () - api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_1HzPeqEm4kUlkaUGES9vPQ5f/confirm:

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:91)

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-clone-36782.cloudfunctions.net/api/payments/create?total=0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I just tried changing my Firebase and Stripe accounts still the same error. Can you suggest what might be the problem. I recreated the app from scratch too. Still this error. I am 1000% sure there is no mistake by me in this code because I have been trying to resolve this for a long time.

Comment: By the way, I have used the Test API Keys not the real API keys for this transaction. And also, I didn't use a real card, I used their default fake one - 42424242424242 . The error may be related to this ?

Answer (score 1):

According to stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment).

`paymentIntent` is only present when the request is successful. Instead of destructuring directly, Could you also check the `errors` object associated with it. And access `paymentIntent` only if there are no `errors` present.

I suggest you log the entire result object first and check what is happening.

Comment: Do you have any idea or suggestions on what the error might be? Kindly inform

Answer (score 1):

The error is (message: "As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports) in my case....

so the confirmCardPayment method  does not return a Payment Intent../

And solution is change currency from 'USD' to other currency like 'INR' in (functions/index.js)

`amount : total,  currency : 'INR'`

Answer (score 1):

The error is (message: **"As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description"**)

Solution is
*Change currency from 'USD' to other currency like 'INR' in* functions/index.js

`amount : total,  currency : 'inr'`

Answer (score 0):

[The `confirmCardPayment` method in Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) does not return a Payment Intent, it returns a `result` object.  In your return handler you should first check for `result.error` and, if that's present, handle it.  Otherwise you can access `result.paymentMethod` (or `result.paymentMethod.id`).

Have a look at this sample code from the Stripe.js reference:

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    payment_method: {
      card: cardElement,
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
    },
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
```

You don't have error handling and you're not looking for the Payment Intent ID in the right place, which is why you're getting the "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in React Application" error.

Comment: Hey, thanks for telling me this, I will try this as soon as possible but how do you suggest I handle  the errors? Please tell

Comment: I tried accessing result.paymentMethod and result.paymentMethod.id but it gives same error that is Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.Then I checked result.error gives Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined. What should I do please any reviews

Comment: It sounds like `result` isn't being defined.  Did you change `}).then(({paymentIntent})=>{` to `}).then((result)=>{` in your code?

Comment: Yes, I tried this too, and then also it gave that cannot read property of undefined

Comment: I changed my code to :-
       `}).then((result)=>{
        console.log("Payment Method Result: " + result.paymentMethod);
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection("orders")

          .doc(result.paymentMethod.id)
          .set({
            cart: cart,
            amount: result.paymentMethod.amount,
            created: result.paymentMethod.created,
          });`

Comment: console.log("Payment Method Result: " + result.paymentMethod); gives              Payment Method Result: undefined

Comment: index.js:1 Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new e (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:12889:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:19328:18
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:19329:10
    at e.onMessage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:19350:6)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:19241:18
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:19279:29
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:31226:25
console.<computed> @ index.js:1

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () -https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_1I0M6KEm4kUlkaUGJdrEOLUU/confirm

Comment: It looks like you're doing `result.paymentMethod` (which doesn't ever exist) instead of `result.paymentIntent`.  Try logging result to see what's inside: `console.log(result);`

Comment: Will try soon .